# triangle inequality TSP is NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

I have been reading online source and it mentioned triangle inequality TSP is NP-complete but without proof. In general, the reduction from HAM-cycle problem to TSP works for asymmetric and symmetric TSP problem. So, I wonder how to start a basic approach to prove triangle inequality TSP is NP-complete.

Comment: It's called metric TSP.  Searching under that term will find many proofs that it is NP-hard.

Comment: Thanks, I had read the proofs but I don't think I understand it, basically they are providing short proofs, but it's similar to original reduction. So, referring to proofs, Instead of setting all edge in G to cost 0, and for all edge not in G to cost 1, they simply set all edge in G to cost 1 and all edge not in G to cost 2. But I'm confused how does this satisfied triangle inequality by increasing cost by 1.

Comment: Please mention in the question what you've read, and what parts you did understand, and which is the first part you didn't understand.  Otherwise, I worry we'll just repeat one of those proofs and then you'll say you didn't understand that either.  Instead of leaving clarifications in the comments, please [edit] your question to expand on these points and provide more background and context about what you already understand and what you're struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept a proof that TSP without triangular equation is NP-complete then it is easy: If you take an instance of "TSP without triangular equation", then you just add a large enough constant to each edge to get the triangular equation, solve it as an instance of "TSP with triangular equation", and that solves your original problem.

Comment: And if @Patrick doesn't accept that (non necessarily metric) TSP is NP-Complete, an easy argument is that (the decision version) of TSP is a generalization of Hamiltonian cycle.